# Как с помощью класса Animation сделать такой вид прокрутки?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-scrollview

Как с помощью класса Animation сделать прокрутку как титры в фильме?

Comment: Какой вид прокрутки вы имеете в виду? Вам нужна просто вертикальная прокрутка списка или что-то еще? Будьте добры, конкретизируйте.

Comment: @Julia, действительно, не очень понятно что именно вы спрашиваете. Если просто прокрутка - то ScrollView/RecyclerView вам в помощь. Но там никаких особых анимаций нет. Просто стандартная прокрутка длинного контента.

Comment: Вы правы, не совсем понятно, извините. Мне нужна плавная вертикальная прокрутка (как в титрах фильмов)